# inconsistent "Invalid JSON from piped input" error from python/powershell

Tags: python, powershell, jenkins

I have a Jenkins instance running on a windows server.  There is a specific job that runs a python script and part of that python script is calling powershell:

```
generate_password = f"""Invoke-Expression $('{PASSWORD}' | op signin --account {ACCOUNT} )
op item create --vault shared title={TITLE} --generate-password='letters,digits,16' --category Password"""
result = subprocess.Popen(["powershell","-Command", generate_password", capture_output=True, text=True, encoding="utf-8")
```

The variables are passed from the Jenkins environment, but I have also tested this where they are hardcoded into the script.

Now I can run the script fine on my local machine with no problems, i can run it on the jenkins server AS the jenkins user with no problems, but the jenkins job itself consistently gets the error "Invalid JSON in piped input".

I've even tried manually creating the script and storing it on the server, then instead of passing the script directly, I call powershell and tell it to run the saved file - this resutls in exactly the same error.

I'm assuming the issue must relate to the Jenkins environment that is spawning the powershell process, but I'm unsure of what I can try to resolve it.

I currently run a variety of python jobs via jenkins (80 or so) and this is the only time I've run into an issue like this.

*edit*:
All of my jenkins pipelines are very simple, they pull a git repo and run a script in that repo.  I'm using jenkins for orchestration only as it has brilliant features for monitoring and scheduling at a price that can't be beat.

*edit*:
I've come up with a work around, I created a scheduled task on the Jenkins server that runs a specific powershell script in a specific location. In my python job I now create that script, call the task, read the output file, then delete the script and the output file.  It's not ideal, but it works.

*edit*:
Interestingly, this very similar code runs fine:

```
share_password = f"""Invoke-Expression $('{PASSWORD}' | op signin --account {ACCOUNT} )
op item share {final_password_name} --vault shared --emails {email_list}"""
result = subprocess.Popen(["powershell","-Command", share_password , capture_output=True, text=True, encoding="utf-8")
```

Comment: How does your pipeline look like? Whats the traceback of the error you are getting? Usually if you want the capture the output of the python script in Jenkins you'll need to run it with the flag `-u` for unbuffered. `python -u myscript.py`

Comment: The error is coming from powershell rather than python, it reads "Invalid JSON in piped input".

Comment: Have you tested passing the parameter `-NonInteractive` and maybe `-NoProfile`? in the python script when running powershell

Comment: Just tested that now but I get the same error.

Comment: "In certain environments, it seems that the CLI interprets a programatic call as receiving piped input when it's not present, in fact." https://1password.community/discussion/comment/641311/#Comment_641311